# PHP SOAP - can't import schema

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to implement `eTeryt` (Polish goverment teritorial service) in my web app.
Documentation says that I have to connect to it using this:

- production service url: https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc
- WSDL service url: https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl

I wrote some piece of code (soap client + login + password provided by service team, needed to access service)

```
$client = new \SoapClient("https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc?wsdl",[
    'login' => 'my_awesome_login_here',
    'password' => 'my_fabulous_password_here',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
]);
```

but executing `CzyZalogowany` function

```
$client->CzyZalogowany()
```

gives me error as follows:

**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://veadmz20:83/terytwcf/TerytWs1.svc?xsd=xsd0'**

No matter if I am using `SOAP_1_2` or `SOAP 1_1`.

Yes - `allow_url_fopen` is enabled

Yes - `open_ssl` is enabled

Yes - I am able to access given URL's via browser

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong URL. According to [official documentation](http://eteryt.stat.gov.pl/eTeryt/rejestr_teryt/udostepnianie_danych/baza_teryt/usluga_sieciowa_interfejsy_api/jakkorzystac.aspx) it's not

`https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/terytws1.svc?wsdl`

but

`https://uslugaterytws1.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl` (production)
`https://uslugaterytws1test.stat.gov.pl/wsdl/terytws1.wsdl` (test)

Also, take a look at my [code to communicate with TERYT webservices](https://github.com/gakowalski/teryt-webservices).